# Criação de dict em python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, lista, dicionário

Time, tem uma classe que cria dicts e armazena-os em slot´s de uma list:

```
class Pagina:

def __init__(self, keys, palavras, tamanhoP):
    aux = list(zip(keys, palavras))
    self.paginas = list()

    for i in range(0, len(aux), tamanhoP):
        self.paginas.append(dict(aux[i:i + tamanhoP]))

def __getitem__(self, num):
    return f'Página {num}: {self.paginas[num]}'

def __repr__(self):
    return f'Todas as páginas: {self.paginas}'

def get_key_pagina(self, num):
    for i in range(0, len(self.paginas)):
        if num in self.paginas[i]:
            return f'Palavra na Página: {i}'
```

Mas preciso agora criar um novo dict em receba as mesmas keys e a posição no dict da classse acima, é possível ?

Segue a minha tentativa até agora:

```
    def novoDict(self, keys):
    aux = list()
    for ii in keys:
        for i in range(0, len(self.paginas)):
            if ii in self.paginas[i]:
                aux.append(dict(aux[ii: i]))
    return f'{aux[0]}'
```

Mas me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required
```

Como ficaria o novo dict, ex:

```
{key 0: Página 0}
```

Exemplo de teste:

```
listaP = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']
listaI = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Instanciando o objeto:

```
x = Pagina(listaI, listaP, 2)
```

Saida:

```
Página 0: {1: 'x', 2: 'y'}
Página 1: {3: 'z', 4: 'w'}
```

O que quero obter:

```
{'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 1, 'w': 1}
```

Comment: Não consegui entender o quer fazer mas [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) deve ser aplicado em iteráveis e no seu caso `ii` é um elemento de `keys` que deve ser do tipo `numpy.int32` e `i` é do tipo `int`.

Comment: Então amigo, quero criar um dict assim: {key 0 : Posição da key na lista "paginas"}, saquei o erro do zip, tentei modificar para o seguinte: (editei na pergunta), mas agora o programa demora muito pra me dar uma resposta da função.

Comment: Alguém consegue ajudar?

Comment: Não seria o caso de substituir toda essa função`novoDict(self, keys)` por essa linha de código `list(zip(keys,self.paginas))` ? Fiz um exemplo simplificado do que entendi do seu problema https://repl.it/repls/BriskFaintFormats , veja se interpretei-o de maneira correta?

Comment: Senho Augusto, a princípio eu tenho uma lista de dict assim: {key: palavra}, onde dependendo do tamanho da página (informação dada pelo usuário), divido essa lista em fatias e armazeno em sub-listas (paginas). A partir disso quero criar um novo dicionário apenas com a key e a posição dela na nova lista (ou seja, na pagina), ex: {key: página 0}

Comment: Falta um exemplo prático para testes. Seria bom umas amostras de dados e um exemplo mostrando os métodos sendo aplicados nesses dados.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107230/discussion-between-barrosfilho-and-augusto-vasques).

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo teste, se puder dar uma olhada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi para que serviria o parâmetro `keys`, pois me parece que você quer gerar um novo dicionário com todas as páginas. Então ficaria assim:

```
def novo_dict(self):
    d = {}
    for i, pag in enumerate(self.paginas):
        for v in pag.values():
            d[v] = i
    return d
```

Eu uso [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para percorrer as páginas ao mesmo tempo em que obtenho o respectivo índice. Ou seja, a cada iteração, a variável `pag` será o dicionário que representa uma das páginas, e o `i` é o respectivo índice.

Depois eu percorro os valores de cada página e adiciono no novo dicionário, associando-os ao número da página (no caso, `i`).

Usando seu exemplo:

```
listaP = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']
listaI = [1, 2, 3, 4]

x = Pagina(listaI, listaP, 2)
print(x.novo_dict())
```

Saída:

```
{'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 1, 'w': 1}
```

Comment: opa, o objetivo era esse mesmo, mas está me retornando um erro: d[v] = i
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: Onde será q tô errando ?

Comment: @barrosfilho_ O código da pergunta não tem nenhum array do numpy. De qualquer forma, se o seu código tem isso, eu sugiro que reveja o seu objetivo ao criar este dicionário, pois arrays, listas e qualquer objeto mutável não devem ser usados como chaves de um dicionário, conforme recomenda a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping).